# Notification Framework - Duplicated messages

Tags: web8.5

I am using the notification framework for publishing the notification messages when an event is executed. 
I am seeing a weird behavior that my notifications get duplicated.
After each occurrence of the event, I get more messages than previously.

[image]

I can see in the logs, that this message is only sent once and the event is also only executed once.

Also, when I reset the cache and reload the browser, the number of occurrences 'resets' - but again, with each execution it goes up.

Here is my NotificationHandler.js code:

```
var notificationHandler = function (event) {
    if (event.data.action !== "client:CreateFolderEventsNotification") {
        return;
    }
    var userSettings = Tridion.ContentManager.UserSettings.getInstance();
    if (event.data.details.creatorId === userSettings.getUserId() || event.data.details.creatorId === "-1") {

        if (Tridion.MessageCenter.getInstance()) {
            var title = event.data.details.title;
            var description = event.data.details.message;

            if (event.data.details.messageType === "Goal") {
                Tridion.MessageCenter.registerGoal(title, description, true);
            } else if (event.data.details.messageType === "Warning") {
                Tridion.MessageCenter.registerWarning(title, description, true);
            } else if (event.data.details.messageType === "Error") {
                Tridion.MessageCenter.registerError(title, description, true);
            } else if (event.data.details.messageType === "Notification") {
                Tridion.MessageCenter.registerNotification(title, description, true);
            } else {
                console.log("Unrecognized message type: " + event.data.details.messageType);
            }
        }
    }
};
var notificationBroadcaster = Tridion.Web.UI.Core.NotificationBroadcaster.getInstance();
notificationBroadcaster.addEventListener("notification", notificationHandler);
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could it be that `notifiationBroadcaster.addEventListener("notification", notificationHandler)' is called for each message/event?

Comment: that's what I think as well, but this is pretty much a code from the sample https://github.com/sdl/publish-transaction-notification/blob/master/ModelExtension/Scripts/NotificationHandler.js

Comment: The more reason to verify it ;)

Comment: Seems likely that the JavaScript code that adds the event listener is being run multiple times. How/where is the script included?