# Notification Framework - Duplicated Messages (2)

Tags: sites-9

When sending a message from the EventSystem (*in a single event and phase*) to the notificationFramework, the message appears multiple times in the messageCenter. When sending a message from a Windows Forms Client the same thing happens. Code is similar to the post below. I verified that the notificationHandler is called multiple times. How can I fix that?

Here's my code:

```
        public void SubScribe()
        {
            EventSystem.Subscribe<OrganizationalItem, SaveEventArgs>(OnOrgItemSave, EventPhases.Initiated | EventPhases.Processed | EventPhases.TransactionCommitted);
        }

        public void OnOrgItemSave(OrganizationalItem orgItem, SaveEventArgs args, EventPhases phase)
        {
            if (phase == EventPhases.Processed)
            {
                if (....) {}
                    args.ContextVariables[Signalr4TridionMessage] = "message to user";
                }
            }
            if (phase == EventPhases.TransactionCommitted)
            {
                if (args.ContextVariables.ContainsKey(Signalr4TridionMessage))
                {
                    string message = args.ContextVariables[Signalr4TridionMessage].ToString();
                    SendMessage(message, orgItem);
                }
            }
        }

        private static void SendMessage(string message, IdentifiableObject CMSObject)
        {
            Session session = CMSObject.Session;
            JObject details = JObject.FromObject(new
            {
                messageTitle = "Message from eventsystem",
                addressedUserId = session.AccessToken.Id.ToString(),
                messageText = message
            });
            NotificationMessage notificationMessage = new NotificationMessage
            {
                Action = "tcm:EventSystem",
                SubjectIds = new[] { CMSObject.Id.ToString() },
                Details = details.ToString()
            };
            session.NotificationsManager.BroadcastNotification(notificationMessage);
        }
```

see also: [Notification Framework - Duplicated messages](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/20260/notification-framework-duplicated-messages/20276#20276)

Comment: Please copy your event handler code, it's possible it's called multiple times.

Comment: I copied the event handler code.